# Adding New Magento Report

Tags: product-images

I am new to Magento.  How can I add a new report to do the following:

Find all enabled SKU's without any images using PHP code?

I know that the site has a post on how to find these items, but I am not sure how I generate that into a report.

The user stated that add the code to "Magento" root.  Being new, I am not sure what this means and what is magento root

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put the code below in a file in the directory where you have installed magento. (where the index.php is located)

The public_html folder for example or htdocs. Or /var/www/ depending on your hosting

```
<?php 

    require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array (
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'like' => 'no_selection'
            ),
            array (
                'attribute' => 'image', // null fields
                'null' => true
            ),
            array (
                'attribute' => 'image', // empty, but not null
                'eq' => ''
            ),
            array (
                'attribute' => 'image', // check for information that doesn't conform to Magento's formatting
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
        ));

    foreach($_products as $_product){

        echo $_product->getSku();

    }
```